# Boxes for code with a horizontal scroll bar each, side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to have:

- some boxes side by side,
- taking up the full width of the view port
- each with equal width
- each with text content where white spaces respected and lines are not wrapped

See my best unsuccessful attempt below. `white-space: pre;` which I have to avoid line-wrap also causes the columns to not have equal width.

How can this be done?

```js
  window.document.querySelector("#xml").textContent = `<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>You should probably need to scroll to see this long line!</body>
  </note>`
```

```css
.columns {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    width:100%
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
}

.code {
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <span id="xml" class="code">
          xml
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <span id="json" class="code">
          json
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I do not misinterpret your question. Just give your columns a width. If you do not want to wrap, you will have to live with scrolling, due to overflow.

```js
window.document.querySelector("#xml").textContent =
`<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>You should probably need to scroll to see this long line!</body>
</note>`;
```

```css
.columns {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
}

.code {
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="column">
    <div id="xml" class="code">xml</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div id="json" class="code">json</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving overflow: auto; from the code class to the column class made the columns equally wide and this solved the problem.

As such:

```js
  window.document.querySelector("#xml").textContent = `<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>You should probably need to scroll to see this long line!</body>
  </note>`
```

```css
.columns {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    width:100%
}

.column {
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1;
}

.code {
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <span id="xml" class="code">
          xml
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <span id="json" class="code">
          json
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```